# IE9 uri encoding issue

Tags: internet-explorer-9, query-string, uriencoding

I am passing a parameter through the query string to a a php page.

The parameter is sent like

```
str=WNQwMGfRxgozriA%2FVvxwuMFIAAD1%2BHXmFjOSUa4tBGM%3D
```

All I'm having the php page do is echo the value of str.

In FF/chrome/IE8 i get the value of

```
WNQwMGfRxgozriA/VvxwuMFIAAD1+HXmFjOSUa4tBGM=
```

However in IE9 i get the value of

```
WNQwMGfRxgozriA/VvxwuMFIAAD1 HXmFjOSUa4tBGM=
```

Notice there's a space instead of + between the 1 and the H.

Does anyone know why it's doing this? %2B is the supposed to be + but it's getting passed as space in IE9.

Comment: +1 very interesting. Is IE doing double-decoding on your string? That's what it sounds like. If so... then... oooh, nasty one.